Why does the Samsung monitor driver installer ask to choose between HDMI and DP?
I have a Samsung monitor
installer app which I downloaded for Odyssey G4 monitor to install the drivers.
Now the installer asks me to choose between:

G40B_SxxBG40x(HDMI)
G40B_SxxBG40x(DP)

Currently my monitor is connected via HDMI.
So I chose HDMI above and it said drivers were installed.
Now, if in the future I connect my monitor via display port, do I need to rerun this installer and choose DP?

Why are you installing an application to use a monitor? You say drivers but you shouldn’t have to install drivers to use a monitor

Almost impossible to tell without knowing anything about the internal design of that monitor and software. That question would best be answered by the manufacturer Samsung, ideally in the documentation accompanying the product. Lacking that, your best approach would be to just try it.

@Ramhound It is not an application just a tool apparently which installs just the drivers. I downloaded it from here:https://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/?model=N0055046&modelCode=LS25BG402ENXGO. Without it in my device manager my monitor was showing up as Generic PNP monitor

Probably? They wouldn't need you to specify which port your using if the driver is capable of both.
It looks like you need to use DP for higher refresh rates, so the HDMI driver may work but with reduced functionality.

Yeah what I know about this monitor is if I want to use Gsync feature which it has I need to use DP port for example
